# odoo.sh warning when creating new module : invalid module names, ignored: shelter

Tags: odoo, odoo.sh

I am new to Odoo.sh.
When I use the editor to create a new module using the scaffold command

```
odoo-bin scaffold shelter
```

The module is named shelter, however, when I try to update current module,
it shows warning:

```
odoo.modules.loading: invalid module names, ignored: shelter
```

When i connect to the build, I was not able to see the new module I build under apps.
Anyone know where the problem is?

Question updated:
In odoo sh, [under odoo folder, tried the update all module command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3Iv3.jpg)

In terminal, the warning shown above went away.
However, still no module found named "shelter" after I activate the dev mode and update the apps list.
[no module found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOQDJ.jpg)

Value of conf file listed:
[conf file list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmlNL.jpg)

Comment: did you make update the module list from the odoo backend interface??

Comment: Yes, the warning occurred when i update the current module in editor is: odoo.modules.loading: invalid module names, ignored: shelter

Comment: I tried the "update all modules" from odoo backend, and the warning goes away but I'm still not able to see my module.

Comment: could you run this command inside odoo folder & update the your question with the result, also please list the value of the conf file 
`find -maxdepth 2 -type d -ls`

Comment: hi Kerbrose, Thanks for the help. I also tried to create a different branch. Same problem still exists. I pretty much don't know what to try next.

Comment: first of all make sure that your module `shelter` is located under `odoo/addons/` or if it is in another directory it must be add to configuration file with values like
```
addons_path = ~/odoo/odoo/addons,~/odoo/addons,~/shelter/
```
the past command you used it in the wrong location. I need you to use it in the correct one

Comment: Hi Kerbrose, Thanks for the help, the module showed up after I put my module folder under odoo/addons.

Comment: I have the same issue. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

well The user is answered in comments. so I am adding the answer for documentation purpose.

when scaffolding a new module make sure that it is added in `addon` path or listed in odoo configuration file.